# django-smart-selects query filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using django-smart-selects to create chained dropdown forms,
problem is I cannot filter querysets made by this package since it creates its own formsets.
normally i would override init such :

```
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['booked_time'].queryset = AvailableHours.objects.filter(status=True)
```

in my forms.py

but now this package is overriding entire form in admin and in user views.
**I need to filter the query so that only objects with Status=True are fetched**

my forms.py :

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookings
        exclude = ('user','booking_code','confirmed',) 

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['booked_time'].queryset = AvailableHours.objects.filter(status=True)
```

my models.py:

```
AVAILABLE_DATE_CHOICES = (
    (True, 'فعال'),
    (False, 'غیرفعال'),
)
class AvailableDates(models.Model):
    free_date = jmodels.jDateField(null=True, verbose_name="تاریخ فعال",)
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=AVAILABLE_DATE_CHOICES,null=True,default=True, verbose_name="وضعیت",)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "روزهای فعال"
        verbose_name = "روز فعال"
        ordering = ['-free_date']
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.free_date)}'

class AvailableHours(models.Model):
    free_date = models.ForeignKey(AvailableDates,verbose_name="تاریخ فعال", null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='freedate')
    free_hours_from = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="از ساعت",)
    free_hours_to = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="الی ساعت",)
    status = models.BooleanField(null=True,default=True, verbose_name="آزاد است؟",)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "سانس ها"
        verbose_name = "سانس"
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.free_date)} - {self.free_hours_from} الی {self.free_hours_to}'



class Bookings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, verbose_name="کاربر",)
    booker_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="نام",)
    booker_service = models.ForeignKey(BarberServices, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='خدمات')
    booked_date = models.ForeignKey(AvailableDates, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,related_name='booked_date', verbose_name="روز",)
    booked_time = ChainedForeignKey(AvailableHours,
                                    chained_field="booked_date",
                                    chained_model_field="free_date",
                                    show_all=False,
                                    auto_choose=True,
                                    sort=True,
                                    null=True,
                                    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                    related_name='booked_time',
                                    verbose_name="سانس",)
    booking_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=random_string, verbose_name="کدپیگیری",)
    confirmed = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=BOOKING_STATUS,default='در انتظار',null=True, verbose_name="وضعیت",)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "رزرو ها"
        verbose_name = "رزرو"
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.booker_name)} - {self.booked_time} ** {self.confirmed}'
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Bookings)
class BookingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['booker_name','booked_time','booker_service','booking_code','confirmed']
    list_editable = ['confirmed']
    list_filter = ["confirmed",'booked_time__free_date']
    search_fields = ['booker_name', 'booked_time__free_hours_from','booked_time__free_hours_to', 'booking_code', 'confirmed']
   
    
@admin.register(AvailableHours)
class AvailableHoursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #form = TimeGenerator
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        frm = obj.free_hours_from
        to = obj.free_hours_to
        date =obj.free_date
        # Ensure from-to range is valid and create objects within the range
        if frm is not None and to is not None:
            items = [
                AvailableHours(
                    free_date=obj.free_date,
                    status=obj.status,
                    free_hours_from=hour,
                    free_hours_to=hour + 1,
                )
                for hour in range(frm, to)
            ]
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)
            
            extra = AvailableHours.objects.get(
                free_hours_from = frm ,
                free_hours_to = to ,
                free_date=date ,
                )
            extra.delete()

    list_display = ['free_date','free_hours_from','free_hours_to','status',]
    list_editable = ['status']
    list_filter = ["status",'free_date',]
    search_fields = ['free_hours_from','free_hours_to','status','free_date__free_date']
```

anyone can suggest any workarounds for this problem ?

Comment: Can you share the `ModelAdmin` you are using?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem 
done

Comment: but where the the `ModelAdmin` (you seem to have only included the models and the `ModelForm`)?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem aw sry missread. included

Comment: so what happens if you set `form = BookingForm` in the `BookingsAdmin`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem 'list' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: not the `TimeGenerator` in the `AvailableHoursAdmin`, but `BookingForm` in `BookingsAdmin`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem well the admin panel option changes according to the form. it works normally same as the form. but my problem is something else, i need to filter the queryset of the django-smart-selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by editing the views.py of the package (smart_selects)

adding a simple filter

```
# Add a filter for status=True
    queryset = queryset.filter(status=True)
```

on line 106 did the trick